# Android base 64 encode string not showing actual image

Tags: java, android, image

Hello I am working with android image processing via base 64 encoding and decoding.I need to send an encoded base 64 string to server as a string . When I tried it in android side , I can able to decode it into original image.and my decoding and encoding are as follows

```
public void base(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        toimag(encoded);
        String a=encoded.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        Log.i("strrr",a);
    }

    public void toimag(String encodedImage)
    {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        logo.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }
```

But I cant able to get the actual image using  http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ . It show only a part of my actual image. This is my base 64 string

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAAJYCAIAAAAVFBUnAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4
    nKS9WbMsyXEm9n0emVVnu/vSDTTQQAMgOCMQHIDkiGM2Gs1QkkmU5kG/QX9QZjKZzYNMD3oZDheJ
    Q2rEAUgNFwCNbqBB9N3vOacqw10P7h4RWXXORdOUuKjOk5WVGYsvny/hwf/p6SMAAMxMLE4AGAuA
    QgJKAwFAxTCpkEaDAFCjKdTMbDZDHCoASUABoAhJkvktRKT96e/yP0UEANXMf4HCIiIiMpGUKkZC
    CKE/QUCSC5Wkt5wksxWlFDOLvpj5K0jSCEDy1d54AALzl0FNVc2MBpJLUQAwMQPV1KrqoqpQq6aq
    WmGqWlUXU1UtYIVVUzUutEW1mpmZclbYAqvgIlJV92bV9HozmZkqDFBKBRbYHqpSjKjEAlaKCoxi
    xN7UIEpAigorBSxKmOxaH8dPo/qA0CA+zgaS1eJcaAAKSAENPioCnwAfZB9c9WcWkKYk/WlUnxaK
    SIFJG+e6+ADGpOe8KKRTQp7QsIiMJNFOlPB59IlK4uzPMbYn+zM1289GeCRNat7PeDIMgGgd6FP8
    vWZWSgnKSabwLogIB/KmAQwKEaAoaPBBVDMzW9Bf1w4lNPgGCiMKygRSROayAcAipBgLhDAhWcsS
    Y0XCJKdYvJ39qzwUNXpk4tMH+AxKDhWGE5TGvgCTcQAQoBoAQkmjGqyq6gRtBw3OMu1XCquImbJo
    W1HGbLFMRHEuNqERwolFSGpysN/fJ7Hzr3QKl9LO1Uyz98bVULTBaXIAQKGMFNLobWH1uVZdYIaq
    VtVQF13MQjK0+81sL07b0W6xIMvd4tPr3F/NzH9Rhe234yGV42NbeyYL+kFjZAJAqTXFYMyj07zI
    hJj47CkIYMEuBnBgCgBag7UluDX4ScucdFtj9ISAWY0/FfCXkzSIGZUw8fkxf4sYKCYIiU2iiJRS
    RIRq0rhUjGTqhernJUR/knqRNo/jUWCNTmyYc5o0RaOq/kMRUV0ORsC7WXVFDH2OBGIgUGAAKswI
    pdZknT7OwzPzEY1PsdDazU1hATA5JNR4bO0yfHzmVd3lWKWwUppZl7DroySBtdHzYQn27Fo7Xldt
    xxDy2RdvodUb73euOx5PgZrQZY4lyQMQznEPNW82AGKbfK5mf5XkAhNXXq6uCQgVMEcjYBtSv67L
    4o/1+XFRoERRl+dVzJuiodZyYJzrLdmtEP5eMwvZqCYGKaGVYogMxSAGZdNm2qeCGtw4Dpy/1fto
    ViVO2890IORh2jSfQAhSrPqjgJGIxMY//TWBjXyYnOaEQonDedCEiBtQgqUClkGSZJlDJoSBoJmx
    vZB0vaMItGECMb8nuzSIadxM/KDBGulbShMd9FW7sxGLqsKM6KoC4G0vaI0xE7ASNChCSLcf+Xnj
    HtcfB5+VgQxiKDoPOCVRYd4d75JPXBsyIzCopdapVQe5YrA2LxxoSvIn2gVTH0wAImKJtscTETMT
    M3MxGV0bcBItpqwDt2H02nNM6ZwGg/faR0CJnOpAVD5JpuoPdKwEBGBhaj+67ACoBDVFAujNs3iS
    JYK3vFZhMJAhWYUkQsO4+At8ICIUByRIMAAAJogBX/X4pjkSvxmAmYAw0/VdHWx5B0KKYVRVUKKZ
    Xk0DKwP7IqFq9NjnxV96E3WPpHJjy288+pPbWwhoaEU1mqkmHR6rGq7RVaOxg1cAsK54JOccjnHH
    nzRg5JQEQM1o0GEMQZjBAIMYq5/rMbbyx47G7aARa3tpooTsSPCLkkxTRMgGJirSREQSLAIHOsNa
    GGAGiDOKE4MDMn+OswmgSkD7AJoZKNlICcMnZEsN4KUGMY7Stw+2DuCBox4ZROYNs3PDsULh4w9u
    uf0WYrvxOhmi0eX8eMWPA3TlXXPGDAHf7hQXdD6GJomrjMdyCwjD9QixpRvCfxpD4njjV6mSdiRe
    PxxSC0VWBrntE+pUt+CmWWgXGoOMzyclZyJmebhnZUgHVfMG26+3xvVtOw/B7HxnqNAchYau/Bg8
    R2JW87sbJcBqGP0uRUh1F+/KUKbO22ZIO3k1wH4+Ba5slzTuo/V2CiyvOGAyklATAAbBCqAUawAi
    wZPbwU26GVxBrgcu+cptIEdQIiJTWj/S4JeQSA/WOCBdDbgCizk+mKRk5vbqENqKdquQR/MryVhM
    UeKWvViqXrKsVUqiqBz1AEM2fEtxp5FBjxjER1VhVFNxHhpsAUujOICXq+LDTwukDoOLUobnDgrX
    Co1QlRjglJlhPUdI4esjFPwPCEGyxKyyAaYVwGo/HD5zMHNC1u+NE3oHpRaKmSlM3G4DEtcwdTya
    RUIoTECFiQVMTHQFY+dqpXkPgtoZ81zMarfG+rGYIr2AwDC4hBpK/t6Fcc2GNvdVawNTmRhBiEmY
    EyxB7kYxUhjO4jDHbTWQTKudHAcbAFAEJjYaj40m0HxaaBirqIAa42mud90bRzdTxUBIRaWZwsKB
    BXPF33DJO8yS4+OGZq+/9ROnhI6xYl5K+ORYAEWaH7/ymUyvhp8PGitwwyjclaAQthL4DRipqsXP
    2+xqbQgcbhCrqpq5oIZaEHT7F6Bdm0G//gQQks3pLQZBAYISvlJKAC1TZ4wm51Jox2hb+/QrUBan
    BAXEisMoAKawLgRNNd7b/MbWmmZqAFnMDAqRcPcy8Ca9AY7oxCCmMrh23GOR86IMkcIUKb8Cf4/T
    vbrzSHYdPOfdj23HjY4hMTQzl6S0V5gzgpKuvwALGFrYTKoRjYE3GIYAYEXHFjYOLlLGP3tf1o7Y
    8cujPwkwXTzdCvVzD0wcMHHSNpqByUD1g+Vzy9GFj2uXdYBidSdqKrj6jvZ0xdOsEcDUnO8iDjZY
    6be9rmG+W77tuGqEN60DFZCwLeDArKmyZpECmBwlWNNMDXkgFIkrr6QJE5AGUSNMXO5QJQlRBi2b
    YxQMM+iV+IdB3rWTKsUaw8nUPVigy24toFOlewtKaUEcax27KUbQhigZm000EkQ1pL1IALIiGsfh
    ZoZ01EULUwQ1uHZM+vkVbJjONk8SADleUUPDpbcg0JeZgeZQ19wB4k9QVRddKztg7C3MSUHdDZaQ
    U0Ga1ogNsdKKdW4RgEA1KwhSbg+VYOfAW0QYxK6Jxv6O7WCXRzeiK0xyZFoFHnUUZcVoQA2bmBqR
    TQdJAeBG7jWX1oYKI6g0N8FzWIOyFTnMoTvSCkoBRGt+DAcjbla4O5KCdluwYunWUtBka9WIoTvm
    8eGU7q81h6aku2V9vihyBFOdpUuctVF1PrLFcZ8pARqzE70NDUkIqBExNmPYWJSUK+6Iq6CYEqgZ
    NdUAug0jmCZl4gscI6G28y5Y1zipy/FwWAoDf4jPVAr81WCM4rWbDX6FMJiQitGiaK6YAC4AKgyE
    gvEvbZqIFrYHKhtbmwV9GkxNQwibe5Q1kVNCrPxz/GztFBNA1ZU0aAjHak2A6SZUBVVB0SDjhoRS
    sAun5Cq2TxgWCSRNsrruzw7BwupQkmM7LZVbCK0wWzLw4dFGhYb56pRVwhCzjn3MSKO5BlWoUYTC
    AkrgsZFamr40Em5ueLNwNMsYFMptlHZwHF9vVCFDRE8MiPBoqA+/LTiTEdkQcQvfobOz0wpdsdH3
    zfgKBjmkWKeB4mQmQXypZw8gxbEaGgfHSf3g4beNTMx7fpliC+u/b+mFQ48BAx80YGiiZjNWfD8S
    gU+ptQavW+iHNo9j9sdSp+fJaEHxoAMHoz2iK79SEYqcoXahaVxmc/02hyI2oYf2VgPsLkpa8LMb
    WEIWhUMdCYayCGMk+7YsnBIdBjNQCj93yhtcu6OFYSJBvjKFyuEU9xAmFGGoHIT136zywFiDSrsB
    wCab+wB1f6tESJuWKi2EWhOa3WrDgEfRQNI7VYuImI15OGaAmgpliNB1zCG3+LQaYwzYS5Vj3slo
    p1JTdIpCIqTl9AcFBXQDVBxjDdQ8uPYxItf8QAHpfkJaSYEmHUqtp6Ah+hzxUYC6
```

How can I resolve this issue ? Is there any problem with this encoded string ? Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what are you doing `String a=encoded.replaceAll("\\s+","");` ?

Comment: this is for testing.remove all white spaces.I didn't used that string

Comment: You never explained the problem. State clearly what you intended

Comment: @UserAndroid what exactly issue you are getting ... image for the base64 which you have given in question is half or part of image as you may have get that from logcat or watch. so dont check with that apply directly that string to converted bitmap to imageview and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are cutting and pasting from the logcat.  logcat truncates long messages, so you should not rely on it for copying large pieces of data.  You should save the base64 string out to a file and then try your validation using that file.

Comment: hello. Some device does not allow to write to file. I use Q-mobile to test write to file, then searching many, many post , but can not make a text file in device (intenal stogare)

Answer (score 0):

**For Encode image to Base64**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
String imageEncode = Base64.encodeToString(b,
Base64.DEFAULT);
```

**For decode image**

```
byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(imageEncode, 0);
Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
logo.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```